# How to use Assembla Webhook with Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, assembla

I want to auto-build my job in Jenkins and I am using assemble, I tried using normal webhook like we do in Github but it is not working please help me on this. If you have done this already.

Comment: I have not tried it but these articles might help.. [this one](https://articles.assembla.com/en/articles/748190-configure-jenkins-ci-integration-with-merge-requests) and [this one](https://plugins.jenkins.io/assembla-merge-request-builder/), please consider adding your own answer if you've found a sulotion :)